# Java Eclipse, image and source path in css

Tags: java, css, eclipse

I'm having problems linking my image source path in Eclipse's Dynamic Web Project. I have my folders like this:

```
WebContent
   css/
      main.css
   img/
      mainbg.jpg
   js/
   META-INF/
   WEB-INF/
   footer.jsp
   header.jsp
   index.jsp
```

I was able to link my stylesheet with `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">` but when I tried linking an image background it doesn't show up. How do I get the right image path? I am very new to Eclipse and Java.

```
background: url("../img/mainbg.jpg");
```

Comment: try: background-image: url("../img/mainbg.jpg")

Comment: @nikhilk - I have, no luck.

Comment: could you paste your code?

Comment: @nikhilk - like.. main.css? Otherwise there's not much code. On header.jsp there's just the `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css">`

Comment: Yes, in main.css you may need to include background-image: url("../img/mainbg.jpg"). Have you tried it?

Comment: @nikhilk - Yes I have, it doesn't work either.